# How to submit a form on page reload with GET request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-core-mvc

I want submit a form with GET request on page reload. How can I achiev this with Javascript/JQuery or without Javascript/JQuery in ASP.NET Core MVC web app. Thanks.

Comment: Share the code of what you have done so far to achieve this and what problem/error you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code
 this will submit on reload

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
   $("form").submit();
});
```

or you can use URL to pass GET value

```
  $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    var v= $("input").val();
    $(location).attr('href', 'http://example.com/index.php?value='+val);
     // or window.location.href='http://example.com/index.php?value='+val;
    });
```

you can use ajax if above method doesn't work

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'script.php',
        async:false,
        data: {value:"username"}
    });
});
```

if async is set to false browser waits for request to complete else it will not.

**that is why above  first two method may not work.**